# CSS | Place div after <p> tag

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am trying to add [this tooltip](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/07/css-inline-help-tips/) right after a p tag's text finishes.

In this example the tooltip show an image when i hover it:

```
<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p> 
<div class="help-tip">
    <p><img src="balloon.jpg" width="300" /></p>
</div>
```

How could i align the .help-tip right after the "This is some text in a paragraph" paragraph?

Regards

Comment: With CSS it would be awkward; can the HTML be reorganised and changed? What exactly do you need to position at the close of the text, just the image? Or is there some reason it's wrapped in two other elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your elements dont align because the img is wrapped with a **p** tag, which automatically changes the line.

```
<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p> 
<div class="help-tip">
    <img src="balloon.jpg" width="300" />
</div>
```

To solve this you have to keep in mind that your container has to be able to contain both elements. So if your **img** is 300 px wide and your **p** element is 150px you need a container larger than 450px.A solution would be to wrap the two elements with a wrapper **div** and and add inline display in css.

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="foo">This is some text in a paragraph.</span> 
    <div class="help-tip">
         <img src="balloon.jpg" width="300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.foo{
 width:150px;
 positition:relative;
}
.wrapper{
     width:550px;
     positition:relative;
}
.help-tip{
    display:inline;   
}
```

### UPDATE

This was not working because the paragraph text was wrappped in **p** element and it was going below by default. If you have to use the **p** element you can use `position:absolute` for the image to align it, or use **span** rather than **p** and use [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajL91qd4/) .

Comment: Whatever... Fastest downvotes ever. Dont hate the player. Hate the tab that doesnt give space but goes on the post button...

Comment: Well, I assumed it was an oversight, and those downvotes aren't mine; they were, however, in the absence of any obvious answer, perfectly justified (and they remain so, if those casting the votes don't think your answer useful).

Comment: I gave you love for the pain I feel for you.

Comment: leonidas, can't agree more on the tab thing >.>

Comment: Ofcourse I understand the point of the downvotes. Anyway I am really glad this worked out!

Comment: By the way doesn't your post totally ignore the fact that he's using the tooltip code as base from the link? He doesn't want to just align some plain html, he wants to modify the example in the link to a single line version.

Comment: mmm this is not working for me...what should be the css for help-tip? I reproduced your answer and in my case the help-tip is not even being displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Edit even better code:

CSS:

```
.help-tip {
    /* remove following css: */
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    /* add following css: */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
<div class="help-tip">
    <p><img src="balloon.jpg" width="300" /></p>
</div>
```

---

Other previous method:

```
.help-tip {
    /* remove following css: */
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    /* add following css: */
    float: left;
    margin: -2px 10px;
}
p {
    /* add following css: */
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: It is not valid to put a `div` element in a `p` element.

Comment: My bad, fixed it. It didn't matter if the tooltip icon was inside or outside the paragraph anyway.